# Ultimate goal of science?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

Sorry if I seem to be redundant about this or if my exposition is not clear enough.

May you help me clarify about what to rationally expect for the 'final explanation' that science could give us when its job is considered done?

I mean, an extrapolation of science's road for the future to come can makes us think that this final answer will be something like this 'outline':

**-Case1:**

***brules(1) = Universe***

meaning that the whole complex Universe we see is the logical result of applying some basic-rules ('brules') to some very simple 'stuff' (expressed by the '1')

That idea seems problematic for science because there seems to be no way to 'explain' the 'basic-rules' and the '1', from this general point of view.

The other alternative 'outline' seems worst:

**-Case2:**

***brules(0) = Universe***
or
***0 = Universe***

where '0' would express the 'absolute nothing'.

Both alternatives for the 'final explanation' seems to suggest the need of the 'unknown' or 'indefinite' as religious people claim.

FYI I am not religious inclined person.

Please help clarify this subject.

Comment: We can rationally expect that no 'final explanation' is forthcoming, and the "theory of everything" is a nice but naive ideal. Explanations, as well as what counts as one, are purpose and background specific, and this means an inexhaustible source of scientific tasks. The 'unknown' or the 'indefinite' are no explanations though, and neither is "because God", so that does not help either. Indeed, the idea of "ultimate explanation" is incoherent, as the [Agrippa's trilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCnchhausen_trilemma) shows.

Comment: So we are doomed to be fools chasing our tails!!!

Comment: That one is "doomed" not to be omniscient does not mean she is a fool, there is big space in between. Science gives us what we need, not what we want, except, maybe, sometimes.

Comment: "Ultimate goal of science?" To understand the world (physical, natural, social, etc.) we live in.

Comment: [put on hold], really? I asked this question on this 'Philosophy' forum because in a debate with other people they show me the above argument outline. We got to a point where I just couldn't figure out of any 'logical' and 'rational' arguments to fight back. That is why I made this request for 'advice' or help.

Answer (score 3):

Science is about describing and predicting phenomena. So science will be "done" when it can accurately and precisely describe and predict all phenomena that can be scientifically determined.

If the rules and any additional assumptions can be shown to meet those requirements, plus can be shown to be irreducible, then we'd be finished. It's probably fair to say that some scientists might be disappointed if the rules themselves weren't sufficient but that would have no bearing on the science itself.

And it would be completely fine (although, again, maybe disappointing to some), if there were unknowns on the proviso that it can be shown that they are unknowable scientifically.

Comment: I can't accept the slogan: Wellcome to the Theist world point of view!

Comment: In my comment above, I really was being sarcastic. I really appreciate your answer and explanation.

Comment: So, there is no room for an explanation in science? Describing and succesfully predicting doesn't seem the same as Explaining. Is that what you are saying here?

Comment: @fante not sure what you mean. Observations can be explained in the context of the assumptions and rules of science. That happens all the time. If you mean does science ask why the rules are the way they are? It can do because that may help elucidate them but it’s not important in any sense. Science would be fine with a set of rules that describe and predict everything even if we have no ‘story’ behind them.

Comment: I guess I understand your position however I don't support it. Maybe I am wrong but I think science gets real progress when it works hard to find out what it is behind what it shows on the surface. Please, may tell why we should consider not important the Why questions? I really want to appreciate your point here.